# Flutter/Arduino/Bluetooth - Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, arduino, bluetooth

I'm making an application connected to Arduino via Bluetooth. It's giving the following error, I believe I'm passing bytes I don't know how to convert.

```
E/flutter (17509): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
E/flutter (17509): f
E/flutter (17509): ^
```

```dart
_onDataReceived(Uint8List data)  {

    //print(data);
    String entrada = String.fromCharCodes(data);

    //print (entrada);

    //testeValor = entrada;

    int dados = int.parse(entrada);

    print(dados);

}
```

Arduino:

```cpp
void loop() {
    
   float frequency = meter.getFrequency();
    
   if(frequency > 0){
   
     //String convert = String (frequency, 0);
     Serial1.write(frequency);
     Serial1.print("\n");
     
     if(Serial1.available()){
       Serial.write(Serial1.read());
     }
   }
   delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Use `Serial1.print(frequency);`. Also you are sending a float and trying to read an int.

Comment: I tried to use Serial1.print but the values ​​arrive wrong, for example: instead of reaching 91, it arrives 9 and then the 1, in separate lines

Comment: Then you need to accumulate the data and try to extract a line.

Comment: But sometimes the value comes out correctly, however it is a problem in the flutter code because I tested it on another device and the value arrived correctly

Comment: Serial is a streaming interface, you aren't guaranteed to get the whole "message" or even only a single "message" in a single read. You need to handle framing of messages yourself. If you send "AB" and "AC", you might get "A","B","C","D" or "ABCD" or even "A", "BCD".

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to handle this data to arrive correctly? why in another application they arrive correctly?